# How to find a distribution function from the max, min and average of a sample

Tags: python, scipy, statistics

Given that I know the, Max, Min and Average of sample (I don't have access to the sample itself). I would like to write a generic function to generate a sample with the same characteristics. [From this answer](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/236449/calculating-distribution-from-min-mean-and-max/236509#236509?newreg=938e966390d2474ba091e0e11938cdaf) I gather that this is no simple task since many distribuitions can be found with the same characteristics.

```py
max, min, average = [411, 1, 20.98]
```

I'm trying to use [scipy.norm](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.stats.norm.html) but unsuccessfully. I can't seem to understand if I can pass the arguments mentioned above or if they are just returned values from an already generated function. I'm pretty new to python stats so this might be something quite easy to solve.

Comment: Can you get the variance/std-dev of the sample ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Triangular distribution should perform your desired task since it takes three parameters (min, mode, max) as inputs that match your criteria. You can think of other distributions such as standard, uniform, and so on; however, all of their input parameters either lack or partially take one of the three input parameters mentioned by you above. If I were in your position, I would consider triangular distribution because even partial exclusion of a single parameter can incur information loss.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
h = plt.hist(np.random.triangular(-3, 0, 8, 100000), bins=200,
             density=True)
plt.show()
```

[Numpy - Triangular Distribution](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/random/generated/numpy.random.triangular.html)

[image]

Comment: This answer is incorrect. Any random distribution that is generated in this matter, regardless of the shape, does NOT guarantee that MIN and MAX are equal to the desired numbers if they would be extracted afterwards.
This is easily checked:

    a = np.random.triangular(-3, 0, 8, 100)
    print(min(a))
    print(max(a))

The limits set in these functions simply state the ALLOWED limits, not the GUARANTEED limits.

Answer (score 3):

As [noted here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/236449/calculating-distribution-from-min-mean-and-max):

> There are an infinite number of possible distributions that would be
> consistent with those sample quantities.

But you can introduce additional assumptions to find **some** solutions:

- Use only fixed list of some popular distributions
- Add constrains on the parameters of a distribution

You can think of this as an optimization problem: find the distribution and its parameters that have the best fit (in terms of specified min/max/avg statistics). In pseudo-code the solution would be something like this:

```
candidates = []
for distribution in distributions:
    best_parameters, score = find_best_parameters(distribution, target_statistics)
    candidates.append((distribution, best_parameters, score))
best_distribution = sorted(candidates, key=lambda x: x[2])
```

Using this procedure you can find that [powerlaw](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.stats.powerlaw.html#scipy.stats.powerlaw) distribution can produce the statistics similar to the desired:

```
s = stats.powerlaw(a=5.0909e-2, loc=1.00382, scale=4.122466e+2)
sample = s.rvs(size=100_000)
print(np.max(sample), np.min(sample), np.mean(sample))
```

Max/Min/Avg:

```
411.02946481216634 0.994030016 20.943683603008324
```

[image]

Full code:

```py
import numpy as np
from scipy import stats
import cma
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt


distributions_and_bounds = [
    (stats.cauchy, {'loc': [-1000, 1000], 'scale': [0, None]}),
    (stats.chi2, {'loc': [0, 1000], 'scale': [0, None]}),
    (stats.expon, {'loc': [-1000, 1000], 'scale': [0, None]}),
    (stats.exponpow, {'b': [0, None], 'loc': [-1000, 1000], 'scale': [0, None]}),
    (stats.gamma, {'a': [0, None], 'loc': [-1000, 1000], 'scale': [0, None]}),
    (stats.lognorm, {'s': [0, None], 'loc': [-1000, 1000], 'scale': [0, None]}),
    (stats.norm, {'loc': [-1000, 1000], 'scale': [0, None]}),
    (stats.powerlaw, {'a': [0, None], 'loc': [-1000, 1000], 'scale': [0, None]}),
    (stats.rayleigh, {'loc': [-1000, 1000], 'scale': [0, None]}),
    (stats.uniform, {'loc': [-1000, 1000], 'scale': [0, None]}),
    (stats.alpha, {'a': [0, None], 'loc': [-1000, 1000], 'scale': [0, None]}),
    (stats.anglit, {'loc': [-1000, 1000], 'scale': [0, None]}),
    (stats.arcsine, {'loc': [-1000, 1000], 'scale': [0, None]}),
    (stats.burr, {'c': [0, None], 'd': [0, None], 'loc': [-1000, 1000], 'scale': [0, None]}),
    (stats.argus, {'chi': [0, None], 'loc': [-1000, 1000], 'scale': [0, None]}),
    (stats.beta, {'a': [0, None], 'b': [0, None], 'loc': [-1000, 1000], 'scale': [0, None]}),
]

target_params = np.array([411, 1, 20.98])


candidates = []
for distribution, bounds in distributions_and_bounds:
    def objective(params):
        sample = distribution(*params).rvs(size=1_000)
        pred_params = np.array([np.max(sample), np.min(sample), np.mean(sample)])
        mse = (np.abs(target_params - pred_params) ** 2).mean()
        return mse

    x0 = np.ones(len(bounds))

    lower_bounds = [bound[0] for bound in bounds.values()]
    upper_bounds = [bound[1] for bound in bounds.values()]

    best_params, es = cma.fmin2(objective, x0, 1, {'bounds': [lower_bounds, upper_bounds]}, restarts=4)
    score = objective(best_params)
    candidates.append((score, distribution, best_params))

best_distribution = list(sorted(candidates, key=lambda x: x[0]))[0]
print(best_distribution)
```

Here the [CMA-ES](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CMA-ES) optimization from package [pycma](https://github.com/CMA-ES/pycma) was for simplicity.

Comment: I upvoted this answer because of the 1st statement: you can't find the distribution. And anything done to try to find one is most certainly pure speculation with no meaningful sense; UNLESS the original data distribution laws are known a priori because the process that generated the min/mean/max is perfectly known (which does not seems to be the case here). One will always find a way to process numbers in a way that is convenient: that's just garbage in/garbage out and/or cherry picking ... probably not anything close to valid science.

Answer (score 1):

Let's try the following function :

```py
import numpy as np
import random

def re_sample(min_v, max_v, mean_v, size):
    """
    Parameters
    ----------
    min_v  : Minimum value of the original population
    max_v  : Maximum value of the original population
    mean_v : Mean value of the original population
    size   : Number of observation we want to generate
    
    Returns
    -------
    
    sample : List of simulated values
    """
    
    s_min_to_mean=int(((max_v-mean_v)/(max_v-min_v))*size)
    sample_1=[random.uniform(min_v, mean_v) for i in range(s_min_to_mean)]
    sample_2=[random.uniform(mean_v, max_v) for i in range(size-s_min_to_mean)]
    
    sample=sample_1+sample_2
    
    sample=random.sample(sample, len(sample))
    
    sample=[round(x, 2) for x in sample] 
    
    return sample
```

When I **test** this function as follows:

```py
sample = re_sample(1, 411, 20.98, 200)

print(np.mean(sample))
print(np.min(sample))
print(np.max(sample))
print(type(sample))
print(len(sample))
print(sample)
```

I get follwoing **Outputs** :

```py
>>> 19.8997
>>> 1.0
>>> 307.8
>>> <class 'list'>
>>> 200
>>> [20.55, 7.87, 3.48, 5.23, 18.54, 268.06, 1.71,....
```

Answer (score 1):

Quick edit with elaboration (I realized this later): you can apply the balancing trick on ANY distribution.

The pain with many of the proposed solutions is that *the chances of hitting EXACT values for MIN and MAX and AVERAGE using floats is basically ZERO*.
Knowing this means that the MIN and MAX values need to be added manually, but adding values mess with the generated distribution.

A naive approach would be something like, where you generate a distribution, add your MIN and MAX, and balance them out to hit the mean:

1. set min and max
2. calculate the mean
3. add points to compensate for the deviation of the desired mean (depends on how asymmetrical the MIN and MAX are placed around the desired mean)
4. create a random distribution that will still fit between the desired mean and the nearest boundary condition after you shift the mean
5. Shift the mean of the distribution to your desired TRUE mean
6. add the generated symmetrical distribution to the data available before point 4.

The initial 3 steps make sure that the boundary conditions (MIN, MAX) do not mess up your AVERAGE.
Steps 4-5 create some data that is guaranteed to have the exact desired AVERAGE, and will fall between the MIN and MAX.
Step 6 combines the data to the desired result.

```
import math
import numpy as np

MAX, MIN, AVERAGE = [411, 3, 20.98]

data = [3, 411]

left = AVERAGE - MIN
right = MAX - AVERAGE
ratio = max(left, right)/min(left,right)

n = math.ceil(ratio) - 1
dx = math.ceil(ratio) - ratio  # this checks overcompensation due to working with integer numbers

data = data + [MIN]*(n) + [AVERAGE + left*dx]  # the second part compensates the overcompensation again :)

print(np.mean(data))
print(min(data))
print(max(data))

N = 1000

width = min(MAX-AVERAGE, AVERAGE-MIN)
print(width)

dist = np.random.normal(AVERAGE, width/3, N)

delta1 = np.mean(dist) - AVERAGE

dist = [x for x in dist if x > (MIN + delta1) and x < (MAX - delta1)]

delta2 = np.mean(dist) - AVERAGE
dist = [x - delta2 for x in dist]

full = data + dist

print(np.mean(full))
print(min(full))
print(max(full))
```

Answer (score 0):

A probability (function) *isn't* sufficiently defined by only it's min, avg and max values. There are (literally) an unlimited number of probability distribution that meet those conditions.

To demonstrate this point, a probability distribution that gives the minimum value with a probability of (max - avg) / (max - min) and the maximum value with a probability of (avg - min) / (max - min) already satisfies those characteristics.

This can be easily verified:

- The minimum and maximum values are trivial.
- The average = probability of minimum * minimum + probability of maximum * maximum = { min * (max - avg) + max * (avg - min) } / (max - min) = (- min * avg + max * avg) / (max - min) = (max - min) * avg / (max - min) = avg.

Also, a Normal distribution is symmetrical *and* not limited in observed values (e.g.: it has no minimum and maximum values).